# Changing src attribute of HTML5 audio element

Tags: javascript, audio, html

I am trying use JS to playback some sounds. What i want to do is have piece of music playing but after a certain time replace it with another audio file. I thought the most effective way would be to reuse the same audio object, but it seems to not kill the original sound so all gets messy. What is the best way to do this?

My code is below, all im doing is passing in a new source at a certain time

```
function inGameSndCreate(src) {
    inGameSnd = new Audio(src)
    inGameSnd.loop = true;
    inGameSnd.play();
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: In which browsers did you test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect you'll need to change the source in the DOM using JavaScript.  The following should work.

```
document.getElementById('audio_id').src = 'different_file.wav';
```